# How to decrease space between indicators in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, indicator

I am using Gnome Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I have noticed that padding between two indicators are too much in shell, which I would like to decrease it.

[image: Check the app-indicators with too much space in between]

I tried using shell extension available but it didn't worked.
Then, I edited gnome-shell.css & decreased padding but surprisingly it didn't worked either.

Please help me in decreasing padding between two indicators in shell.
Thanks.

Comment: Which shell extension did you use? ([this one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/355/status-area-horizontal-spacing/)? - note you need to set in its settings what spacing to use. Also, what shell theme are you using, with what shell version?

Comment: Yup. But even after installing that extension. It doesn't shows u in Gnome-tweaks. Shell version : 3.10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with some Gnome extensions, installing doesn't work if the extension says it does not support that version of Gnome - even if it does work. So to install it:

- Download the extension from the [extension homepage](https://bitbucket.org/mathematicalcoffee/status-area-horizontal-spacing-gnome-shell-extension):
  [`https://bitbucket.org/mathematicalcoffee/status-area-horizontal-spacing-gnome-shell-extension/downloads/gnome3.8_status-area-horizontal-spacing@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com.zip`](https://bitbucket.org/mathematicalcoffee/status-area-horizontal-spacing-gnome-shell-extension/downloads/gnome3.8_status-area-horizontal-spacing@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com.zip)
- Extract the `status-area-horizontal-spacing@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com` folder to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/status-area-horizontal-spacing@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com/`
- Run `gedit ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/status-area-horizontal-spacing@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com/metadata.json`, and edit the `shell-version` to include `3.10`:

  ```
     "shell-version": [
      "3.4", 
      "3.6", 
      "3.8",
      "3.10"
    ],
  ```
- Enable the extension from Gnome Tweak Tool. This method works with quite alot of extensions, but does not always work. You may need to restart the shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+`r`

You can also modify the theme to have a different spacing - this can be done by finding the theme's directory (e.g. `/usr/share/themes/ZukitwoGreen/gnome-shell`, `~/.local/share/themes/ZukitwoGreen/gnome-shell`), and editing the `gnome-shell.css` file to have a different `hpadding` (you can use find and replace) - e.g. mine is:

```
-natural-hpadding: 4px;
-minimum-hpadding: 4px;
```

I think this is also available as a option under the ['Elegance colours'](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/highly-configurable-elegance-colors.html) customizable theme.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I was editing gnome-shell.css in /usr/share/gnome-shell & it didn't worked. After reading your comment I edited gnome-shell.css under .local directory & it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for extensions. In Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome 3.28.4), the stylesheet is named `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`. Around line 680:`.panel-button` > `natural-hpadding` must be adjusted. If the space is still too big for your taste, also reduce `minimum-hpadding`:

```css
#panel .panel-button {
    -natural-hpadding: 12px;  /* change HERE, e.g. 6px */
    -minimum-hpadding: 6px;   /* and here, e.g. 3px */
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #eee;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    transition-duration: 100ms;
}
```

If you don't want to restart, you can also only reload the theme via

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.loadTheme();'
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468660/209677).

Comment: They will be changed automatically to the their default values when you upgrade Ubuntu, right?

Comment: I don't remember any change, and doesn't seems to be part of any package (`dpkg -S /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`). In that case I would [use `dpkg-divert`](https://askubuntu.com/q/1083055/349837) (and a backup :) )